Error terms in the Richardson extrapolation.
The details of what is happening are not important the question I have. We have a solution $X_t(\omega)$ to a stochastic differential equation and an approximation with step size $N$ denoted $Y_t^N(\omega)$. Now a theorem (talay-tubaro; similar to the Richardson extrapolation) tells me that $\mathbb{E}[f(X_T)]-\mathbb{E}[f(Y_T^N)]=\frac{C_1}{N}+ \mathcal{O}(N^{-2})$, this fact leads to an improved scheme with error: $K:=\mathbb{E}[f(X_T)]-2 \mathbb{E} [f(Y^{2N}_T)]-\mathbb{E}[f(Y_T^N)] \in \mathcal{O}(1/N^2)$. However, this seems to imply that $C_1/N+\mathcal{O}(1/N^2)=\mathbb{E}[f(X_T)]-\mathbb{E}[f(Y_T^N)] - K = \mathbb{E}[f(X_T)]-\mathbb{E}[f(Y_T^N)] - \mathbb{E}[f(X_T)]+2 \mathbb{E} [f(Y^{2N}_T)]+\mathbb{E}[f(Y_T^N)] =2\mathbb{E}[f(Y_T^{2N})]$. But the last term can’t behave like $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty } 2\mathbb{E}[f(Y_T^{2N})] =0$, since it should obviously converge to $2\mathbb{E}[f(X_T)] \neq 0$.
I must be getting something wrong that’s probably quite obvious, so I’d be very happy if someone could clear up my confusion.

The error is a matter of single wrong sign.
The complexity of notation obfuscates the matter, so I shall choose a simpler notation. The real objective is to estimate a target value $T$ using approximations $A_n$. We have
$$ T - A_n = \frac{\alpha}{n} + g(n), \quad g(n) \in O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right).$$
It follows that
$$ T - A_{2n} = \frac{\alpha}{2n} + g(2n).$$
We conclude that
$$ \begin{align} A_{2n} - A_n & = (T - A_n) - (T - A_{2n}) \\
&=\left(\frac{\alpha}{n} + g(n)\right) - \left(\frac{\alpha}{2n} + g(2n)\right) \\ 
&= \frac{\alpha}{2n} + g(n) - g(2n) \end{align} $$
or equivalently
$$ \frac{\alpha}{2n} = A_{2n} - A_n + g(2n) - g(n)$$
It follows that
$$T - A_{2n} = A_{2n} - A_n + 2g(2n) - g(n)$$
or equivalently
$$T = A_{2n} + (A_{2n} - A_n) + 2 g(2n) - g(n).$$
We conclude that
$$T = A_{2n} + (A_{2n} - A_n) + l(n), \quad l(n) \in O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
The issue arose because the improved approximation was mistakenly perceived to be
$$M_n = A_{2n} + (A_{2n} + A_n)$$
instead of the correct value which is
$$B_n = A_{2n} + (A_{2n} - A_n).$$

While this is irrelevant to the matter at hand, there are good numerical reasons for not computing $B_n$ as $$B_n = 2 A_{2n} - A_n$$ which is why one should hesitate to do the reduction. In particular, if $A_{2n}$ is already a good approximation, then we do not have to compute the difference $A_{2n} - A_n$ with great accuracy and it rarely matters that it can cancel catastrophically.

You are very correct, thank you so much!

@HenryT. You are very welcome.
